# Develop common Dialog Box Service using Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on Angular 7 and looking to develop common component or service to show **Alerts/Dialog Box when User Confirming/Deleting** details on button click.

I went through link: https://firstclassjs.com/create-a-reusable-confirmation-dialog-in-angular-7-using-angular-material/ and on web I found the many people are using Angular Material way to implement.

Is there any simple way to dynamically pass the `title` and `message` to alert service or component based on action like Update/Delete you're performing?

Comment: Do you want to show your own dialog? or using some existing dialogs? in both case can you please create stackblitz for it to include your dialog then we can show you how to have a service to open that and waiting for response

Comment: @Reza - I am ok to use Own or Custom dialog box. However if you can show both, would be great for all followers

Comment: There are many different ways, so I would say choose one and go for it

Comment: I will, the idea is having a dialog in your app.component, then having service with observable, app.component subscribes to that service when flag is changed it will show the dialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200515/discussion-between-paa-and-reza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [app.component.ts](https://github.com/vikobg/first-class-js/blob/master/angular-confirmation-dialog/src/app/app.component.ts)
you need to extend `openDialog()` like this:

```
openDialog(title: string, message: string): void {
    this.title = title;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      width: '350px',
      data: message,
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        console.log('Yes clicked');
        // DO SOMETHING
      }
    });
  }
```

And extend ([app.component.html](https://github.com/vikobg/first-class-js/blob/master/angular-confirmation-dialog/src/app/app.component.html)) like this:

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog('I am the Title', 'I am the content-message ')">Confirm box</button>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Can we used it in service and use it everywhere we need it ?

Comment: Also I am using <a> tag as hyperlink to show the alters. What would I need to use instead of `mat-button` ?

Comment: Sure.
Just extract the methods (and the title) from `app.component.ts` to a service (like `dialog.service.ts`).
Then you can inject the service in every component you need.

Comment: Thanks working, however I've seen that 'Yes' or 'No' click sometimes doesn't works well. I dont know why is this happening. No logs and control not coming over debug

Comment: It looks like `openDialog` is not working properly with my Custom CSS, however I would need to use Custom dialog box??

Comment: Great! So your initial question is answered?
Styling and "YES" "NO" bug is a different question I think.

Comment: It should be possible to style the dialog box without braking it. You don't need a custom dialog box. Please specify the problem in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you follow the link you provided.

- add a new service like `confirmDialogService`
- Service will have an observable like `openDialog$: Subject<{title: string, message: string}> = new Subject<{title: string, message: string}>();`
- Service will have a method called `openConfimDialog(string message, string title) { this.openDialog$.next({title, message}) };`
- Inject this service in App.Component and subscribe to openDialog$, then inside subscription call `openDialog()` method from link you provided and also pass message and title to the dialog
- Inject the service in the component you want and call openConfirmDialog

at this point you should be able to see the dialog will be opened.

next step is to receive if the user confirm or cancel dialog.

use the same pattern to have another observable `afterClosed$` in service and a method to called `notifyDialogClosed`

now this time call  `notifyDialogClosed` from app.component and subscribe to `afterClosed$` in your component, just don't forget to unsubscribe

If you create stackblitz of that link you provided I can help you for the rest