# Angular Dialog box service issue

Tags: angular7

I am extending my question here: [Develop common Dialog Box Service using Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272140/develop-common-dialog-box-service-using-angular-7/58299759?noredirect=1#comment102964098_58299759). I found that because I have custom style.css file which is overriding the `openDialog` width and everything and its coming to the footer part in my application. When I click on 'Yes' or 'No', then nothing happens, if I click few times then only it works.

I don't see anything wrong/error coming to console and no control to debug coming etc.,

```
openDialog(title: string, message: string): void {
    this.title = title;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      width: '350px',
      data: message,
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if(result) {
        console.log('Yes clicked');
        // DO SOMETHING
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: please share the custom style CSS

Comment: @brandt.codes - Added awr.min.css file here: https://github.com/javaHelper/angular7/edit/master/reactive-form-validations/README.md which is customized css file

Comment: The link target is a README file, not a CSS :-/

Would you paste your code/project at https://stackblitz.com/ or github?

Comment: @brandt.codes - If you look at the end of the file. I have pasted whole file. Unfortunately I cant share code due to security reasons, however if you can provide sample code that will help

Comment: Security/iP is not considered a valid reason to not share existing work here. If a question does not have a [mcve] then it is liable to be put on hold.